# The remove() function is deleting every element I clicked instead of the one recently clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a gallery web app just for fun. I am adding context menu to manipulate images. I added the functionality to delete a certain image by right clicking on it but when a right click on multiple images and click on delete option once, all the previously clicked images also gets removed.

The delete option should delete the recently clicked image only.

```js
$(".image").on("mousedown", function(event) {
  var i = $(this);
  var c = $(".context");
  c.css("display", "none");

  if (event.which == 3) {
    c.css({
      "top": event.pageY + "px",
      "left": event.pageX + "px"
    }).slideDown();

    $("#delete").on("click", function() {
      var p = i.offset();
      i.next().css("margin-left", "290px");
      i.css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": p.top - 72,
        "left": p.left - 10
      });

      i.animate({
        top: "-50%",
        opacity: "0"
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        i.next().animate({
          "marginLeft": "10px"
        });
        i.prev().animate({
          "marginRight": "10px"
        });
        i.remove();
      }, 200);

      c.css("display", "none");
    });
  } else if (event.which == 1 || event.which == 2) {
    c.css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the same context menu is been used for all the images, the reason multiple images are been deleted is because your code adds multiple events to the shared `#delete` button.

One solution to this issue is to add the event for `#delete` once outside of the `mousedown` event. Within the `mousedown` event you then tag the image with a CSS class and target it in the `#delete` event handler.

Example:

```
    $(".image").on("mousedown", function(event) {
      var i = $(this);
      var c = $(".context");
      c.css("display", "none");

      // Deselect any previously selceted images
      $('.image.selected').removeClass('selected');

      if (event.which == 3) {
        c.css({
          "top": event.pageY + "px",
          "left": event.pageX + "px"
        }).slideDown();

        // Tags the image with the `selected` class
        i.addClass('selected');

      } else if (event.which == 1 || event.which == 2) {
        c.css("display", "none");
      }
    });

    $("#delete").on("click", function() {
          // Target selected image
          var i = $('.image.selected');
          var c = $(".context");
          var p = i.offset();
          i.next().css("margin-left", "290px");
          i.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": p.top - 72,
            "left": p.left - 10
          });

          i.animate({
            top: "-50%",
            opacity: "0"
          });

          setTimeout(function() {
            i.next().animate({
              "marginLeft": "10px"
            });
            i.prev().animate({
              "marginRight": "10px"
            });
            i.remove();
          }, 200);

          c.css("display", "none");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because .on attaches the click event handler to the delete button without overriding the last event.

So each right click, which I believe right click is the contextmenu event, it's adding on to the attached events.

When delete is pressed, all of the attached events get fired.

You need to use .click() or use .unbind('click'), to unbind the last event first.

Comment: how can I differ between a right or a left click using click()?

Comment: No way using the jquery click function.  You would have to use .on('mousedown'... or .on('click'... along with .on('contextmenu'...  There is a jquery function, .contextmenu() for right clicks, that will avoid attaching event handlers one after the other.   However, separating out the .on('click'... event, as in the accepted answer, avoids the problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

on line 4 : I think it should be remove since it adds css attrs `{display:none}` in all cases.

```
$(".image").on("mousedown", function(event) {
  var i = $(this);
  var c = $(".context");
  // c.css("display", "none"); //should be removed
 //....
 });
```